# JRE 9.01 - JWS error when invoking applet

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp, oracleforms

Im using Oracle JRE 9.1, and trying to execute an applet (Oracle Forms) through Java Web Start. On my JNLP file its defined by the tag applet-desc.

It works on Oracle Java 6,7 and 8. But with the version 9, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class oracle.forms.engine.Main
 (in unnamed module ... ) cannot access class sun.applet.AppletViewer 
(in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not
 export sun.applet to unnamed module ...
```

I know that applets are deprecated on 9, but it should be only a warning right ?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: No, Java 9 is GA, which you could easily have determined for yourself by simply going to the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: See "[Oracle Forms won’t run on Java 9 – now what?](http://www.vesterli.com/2017/10/16/oracle-forms-wont-run-on-java-9-now-what/)".

Comment: Im not reading GA in that page. However, I'll edit the question.

Comment: True, you're reading version 9.0.1, and you're *not* reading EA (Early Access). And if you had bothered to google [`java 9 release date`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+9+release+date), i.e. done some **research** of your own, you'd have found multiple links saying that Java 9 was release on September 21st, 2017, almost 3 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 9 is not supported by Oracle Forms.
You should still use Java 8.

They have also posted an article that says that Oracle Forms won't support java 9 in the future.